# How to write "Chapter 1" instead of "1" in table of contents of a thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

Suggest me `LaTeX` command and package on how the words `Chapter 1` can be appeared in the table of contents instead of just `1` and so on for the next chapters.
Following is the template of the thesis of our university:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,left=1.5in,
right=1in,top=1in, bottom=1.33in, footskip=0.33in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
%{\vspace*{\fill}
    %\titlerule[1pt]
    %\vspace{1pc}
    %\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
%{1pc}
%{\titlerule\Huge}
%[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename
    \ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}




%\usepackage{microtype}
\overfullrule=5pt
\hfuzz=20pt
\vfuzz=20pt
\hbadness=10000
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{\chaptername\  \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
    \markright {\thesection.\ #1}}
\parindent0pt
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
    {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
\setlinespacing{1.5}
\newtheorem*{theorem-non}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newenvironment{proof}%
{\medskip\par\noindent{\bf Proof\;}}%
{\hspace{\fill}$\Box$\medskip\par}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\numberwithin{lemma}{chapter}
\numberwithin{corollary}{chapter}
\numberwithin{example}{chapter}
\numberwithin{remark}{chapter}
\numberwithin{definition}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\hyphenpenalty 50
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]}{\centering #1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newgeometry{left=1.5in, right=1.0in, bottom=1.75in, top=1in, footskip=0.75in}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
%    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.5cm}
%    \addtolength{\textwidth}{0.0cm}
%    \addtolength{\topmargin}{0.0cm}
%    \addtolength{\textheight}{0.0cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} \setlinespacing{1.5}
%\input{Acknowledgement}
\newpage
\input{mytitle.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{chap1.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap2.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap3.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap4.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap5.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap6.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap7.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{chap8.tex}
\input{bib.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Table of contents have the following command:

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Off-topic: (a) Don't load the `epstopdf` and `epsfig` packages. (b) Don't load the 
`subfigure` package, as it's badly depecated; instead, load either `subfig` or `subcaption`. (c) Don't specify the option `pdftex` while loading `graphicx`. (d) Load `xcolor`, not `color`.

Comment: For the sake of obtaining a useful answer to your query, your code could be stripped down to its essentials, e.g., `\documentclass{book} \begin{document} \tableofcontents \chapter{AAA} \section{A1} \section{A2} \chapter{BBB} \section{B1} \section{B2} \end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico: Hear hear. In order to help we need to know what code you have used. Do not rely on anyone else guessing what you might have done. If you are using a package then ask the package creator

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you employ the `tocloft` package to achieve your formatting objective. Observe that the *only* thing the code shown below does is to insert the word "Chapter" (and space) before the chapter number. In particular, the appearance of `section`-level entries in the Table of Contents is not modified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter }
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\widthof{\large\textbf{Chapter 1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{AAA}
\section{A1}
\section{A2}

\chapter{BBB}
\section{B1}
\section{B2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, I used \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} instead of  \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} as it was making error. Moreover, now the problem is that we have "Contents" instead of "Table of Contents" as the main heading. We want to achieve "Table of Contents".

Comment: @user20255650 - Repeat after me: "The `subfigure` package is deprecated and shouldn't be used." Just because the `tocloft` package can work around some (but not all) of the problems created by the `subfigure` package is in no way a valid reason for using the `subfigure` in the first place. If your document contains subfigures and/or subtables, I suggest you look into using the `subfig` or `subcaption` package. To change the title, run `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}` in the preamble. (`\contentsname` is a macro provided by the `book` document class.)

Comment: Thank you very much again for your prompt and kind response. subfig and subcaption both are generating errors. Morover, I want to add that in the table contents as in sections and subsections there is a dotted line between the section/subsection title and page number, university format requirement is that there must also be a dotted line between Chapter and its pg number, for example " Chapter 1 Introduction . . . . . . . . . . 1 ". Last thing references are not the separate chapter. However, it must appear in the table of contents also with dotted lines also need to be present here as above.

Comment: Instead of dribbling out your requirements one by one, could you *please* edit your posting to list all of them at once? You say something is “generating errors” — what are you doing, and which error messages are you getting? Is merely loading a package causing an error?!